# mrt:accounts-stripe - meteor stripe login

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, stripe-connect, meteor-packages

I'm using [mrt/accounts-stripe](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/accounts-stripe) package to connect users' `Stripe` account to create transfers (payouts) to their account.

Basically what I've done so far, is to let the users login or create the account in my platform (even if it's not a `Stripe` one) and allow them to login via stripe to connect the account and let them receiving money from my service.

The problem is that once called the `Meteor.loginWithStripe` function of the package, it performs a logout and a login with the `Stripe` email and I don't want this kind of situation as it must keep the user's informations and connect the account instead of create a new one.

I'm using also these packages

```
accounts-ui
accounts-oauth
```

### client side

```
Meteor.loginWithStripe({
      stripe_landing: 'login',
      scope : "read_write"
    }, function (err) {
        if (err){
          console.log('stripe error : ' + err); 
        } else {
          console.log('NO ERROR ON LOGIN'); 
        }
    });
```

### startup and settings

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({ service: 'stripe' },{
  $set: {
    service: 'stripe',
    appId: stripeAppId ,
    secret: stripeSecret,
    scope: 'read_write', 
    stripe_landing : "login"
  }
});
```

How to keep the logged user and connect the Stripe account instead of logout and login with the Stripe account user infos?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging multiple user accounts with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124299/merging-multiple-user-accounts-with-meteor)

Comment: if the stripe email is the same as the already logged one, it will never fire the onCreateUser event, but actually is logging in without to create a new user. I'm trying to update the package by changing the redirect uri.

Comment: Then look at accounts-meld or accounts-merge. They don't support stripe but you should be able to either suggest an upgrade or create your own code.

Comment: it works with accounts-meld

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just to add the [accounts-meld](https://github.com/splendido/meteor-accounts-meld/) package to the meteor project